# Strange behaviour of type command

Tags: bash, command

I sometimes use the **type command** to view my codes:

```
$ type squared
squared is a function
squared ()
{
    local t=$(($1*$1));
    echo $t
}
```

I can do the same with builtin functions:

```
$ type __expand_tilde_by_ref
__expand_tilde_by_ref is a function
__expand_tilde_by_ref ()
{
    if [[ ${!1-} == \~* ]]; then
        eval $1="$(printf ~%q "${!1#\~}")";
    fi
}
```

But if I put those commands in this script:

```
$ cat testit.sh
#!/bin/bash
source  ~/bin/all-my-functions.sh
type squared
type __expand_tilde_by_ref
```

and run it:

```
$ ./testit.sh
```

I get:

```
squared is a function
squared ()
{
    local t=$(($1*$1));
    echo $t
}
./testit.sh: line 4: type: __expand_tilde_by_ref: not found
```

It doesn't recognise the builtin command. Why?

I checked type and it is not an alias:

```
$ type -t type
builtin
```

Comment: __expand_tilde_by_ref is not a builtin function. It's some function that your interactive shell picks up from somewhere and that the noninteractive shell that executes you script does not have access to.

Comment: Please do not focus on __expand_tild_by_ref which is just an example. If you try any of the item put out by declare -f the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__expand_tilde_by_ref` is likely defined in `/etc/bash_completion` (actually `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`). Look at your `~/.bashrc`, there should be some lines to include `/etc/bash_completion` only if it's an interactive shell, and are not applied for a script file.

Comment: You are quite right. I added . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion in the script before using type and it behaves as it should. Many thanks.